# How to render the HAML template with haml.js in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, haml

I need to render HAML templates in my Node.js/Express application.
I tried to configure haml.js as views renderer:

```
haml = require('hamljs')
...
app.set('view engine', 'hamljs')
app.engine('.haml', haml.render)
```

And the code in my `GET /` handeler:

```
options =
    layout: "layout.haml"
    locals:
        message: 'world'
res.render('index.haml',options)
```

But application doesn't receive any data.

The is another example in haml.js [documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/haml.js):

```
app.engine('.haml', require('hamljs').renderFile);
```

But there is no such function.

Comment: I didn't find any proper solution. It seems like haml.js can't work as middleware(?). So I rendered it manually.

Comment: same thing happened to me. But I was able to render fine using consolidate. I'll have a closer look today, probably I'm just using the wrong method to get it working with express naturally. BTW, @SergeyVernidub I would love to see an example of manual rendering.

Comment: You should try to use this manual for package https://github.com/visionmedia/haml.js/ , maybe this issue was solved.

You can use this example for manual rendering - https://github.com/visionmedia/haml.js/blob/dc3966fb820869f551eccd5056ad7e62782d45d7/examples/example.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up the haml templating engine did not work for me either. And as there are a few outdated pages out there on that topic, which could be a bit confusing, here is the 'manual way' which worked for me:

```
var haml = require('hamljs');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var hamlView = fs.readFileSync('views/home.haml', 'utf8');
  res.end( haml.render(hamlView, {locals: {key: 'value'}) );
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```